# RSA certificate configured for localhost.localdomain:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Tags: apache2, ssl

I got this error when setting up ssl on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (apache2, openssl)

```
AH01909: RSA certificate configured for localhost.localdomain:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

Any thoughts on what might be going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/578061/rsa-certificate-configured-for-server-does-not-include-an-id-which-matches-the-s

Comment: Thank you for that post, I tried the command in the post: `openssl x509 -in server.crt -noout -subject`... This generated another error: `Error opening Certificate server.crt
140202961364640:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:398:fopen('server.crt','r')
140202961364640:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:400:
unable to load certificate`

Comment: I should have checked back in when I fixed this, but my solution was just to re-do all the steps, re-generate my ssl certificate and then re-make my ssl.conf in apache. I followed these steps if that helps anyone: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04 Of course I actually used a purchased cert... but the steps are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to certificate folder and if you have .pem file,
This worked for me:

```
$ openssl x509 -in nagios.pem -noout -subject
```

You should get something like:

```
subject= /C=AU/ST=Australia/L=Adelaide/O=Australian web agency/CN=Your.Server.Common.Name/emailAddress=whateverItIs@gmail.com
```